# 4 byte unsigned int in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, types

Is there a 4 byte unsigned int data type in MS SQL Server?

Am I forced to use a bigint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't seem so.

Here's an article describing how to create your own rules restricting an `int` to positive values.  But that doesn't grant you positive values above `2^31-1`.

http://www.julian-kuiters.id.au/article.php/sqlserver2005-unsigned-integer

Answer (score 15):

Can you just add/subtract 2,147,483,648 (2^31) to the regular int ?  (subtract on the way in, & add coming out)
I know it sounds silly, but if you declare a custom datatype that does this, it's integer arithmetic and very fast.... It just won't be readable directly from the table

Comment: Would there be a potential for overflow?

Comment: No, your application values from 0 to 2^32 - 1  would map to the database values of  - 2^31 - + 2^31 - 1

Comment: Before google analytics came out, there were a lot more companies making web statistics tracking software. I remember that this is the way a lot of them stored IP addresses without going to bigint...

Answer (score 0):

You can use bigint with checked the constraint, but datatype will still in 8 byte :(

Comment: that's why this is not a viable solution at all

Answer (score -3):

I used BINT(11) instead of INT(11), and it acts as UNSIGNED INT(11)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not a valid answer for SQL Server. The question was asked with the `sql-server-2005` tag.