# Blocking users by IP Address

Tags: sql-server-2008, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Max length for client ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076714/max-length-for-client-ip-address)

I need a way to block users from their IP if necessary.  What's the best way to approach this?  Can I use Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] and store the ip address as a string in the DB?  What lenght would be appropriate for the varchar?

Thanks

Comment: Depends. Do you support IPv6?

Comment: I'm actually not too sure, I'm with discountasp

Comment: You should know that many people are behind a router these days so blocking an ip will block everyone behind the router AFAIK.

Comment: see if this link is of any help to you https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Answer (score 1):

We did the same thing in one of our apps and the approach we took was to create a custom HttpHandler which was wired up to the `Application_BeginRequest` event.

Inside the handler we grabbed the IP address of the request by doing `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` and then performed a check against our list of blocked IP addresses. The blocked IP's are all stored in the database but we also hold a cached copy in memory in the server to avoid trips to the database on every request.

There is a pretty good article on MSDN about creating a custom HTTP Module [Walkthrough: Creating and Registering a Custom HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx)

For what it's worth we store the IP's as strings in the DB but there is some good info on the best format to use in the posts already added.

Answer (score 0):

You could either store IP as a varchar of length 16 or you could store single integer `b1 + b2 * 255 + b3 * 255^2 + b4 * 255^3` where b1 to b4 are fields from ip, as `b1.b2.b3.b4` You could use other checksum but there is no point for storing long ip as string.

Comment: This would not cater for IPv6.

Comment: Right, my bad, but some checksum would be better than whole ip, this would have constant length.