# Getting the IP adress of the computer in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How do I fetch the IP address of a user, then store it into a MySQL table?

Answer (score 4):

Your title says implies one question, and the question text is another. PHP stores the IP of the user as `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. You can stuff that into MySQL directly as a string, or convert it to an integer, in which case you'd have to consider someone coming in via IPv6 and having a 128bit IP address, not just 32bit.

Answer (score 3):

You should read the following articles:

- How to get the real IP address using PHP:
  http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/getting-real-ip-address-in-php.html
- How to store the IP address in MySQL:
  [Max length for client ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076714/max-length-for-client-ip-address)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437771/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-a-php-webservice, getting an IP in PHP is done by accessing the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable.

To store an IP in MySQL easily, you can either

- use a CHAR(15)
- use the INET_ATON(expr) function