# Extract IPv6 address from string

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I currently have formed a KQL that extracts ipv4 address from a string. similarly I would need to extract ipv6 address from the string

ipv4 extract query:

```
datatable (ipv4text:string) 
[
'This is a random text that has IP address 128.0.0.20 that has to be extracted'
]
|extend pv4addr = extract("(([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.(([0-9]{1,3})))",1,ipv4text)
```

I tried the below but not sure if it covers all the edge cases

```
datatable (ipv6:string) 
[
'IPv6 test 198.192.0.127 2345:5:2CA1:0000:0000:567:5673:256/127 in a random string'
]
|extend Ipv6Address = extract(@"(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:){1,7}\:",1,ipv6)
```

Can any of you one provide a complete KQL(or suggestions/hints) to extract IPV6 address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex patterns can be simplified.

Below are the "happy paths". If it's there it will be extracted.
Theoretically you might get false positives, although less unlikely with a real-life data.
If needed, we can add some protection layers.

```
datatable (ipv4text:string) 
[
    'This is a random text that has IP address 128.0.0.20 that has to be extracted'
]
| project pv4addr = extract(@"(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}", 0, ipv4text)
```

| pv4addr |
| --- |
| 128.0.0.20 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0VOwQqCQBS8L+w/DF5UWEStQwRB124dumWHp7ukUSq7jwisf+9JSG8eA8Ob4Y0lFtR3h6Qbn2t2L94G9l1/TaHVWSvIxKe2C5AleOrt8MDsA7fEaCngcARZ610IKMpNlgvK/H/mAbWDJDw17Gys1UWrN0Y/3FzDkLdzGrvFkuyjpLJTYVafKksn4Z+IDHKDpWb6BatSuEu7AAAA)

IPV6 can become a mess (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Representation).
I would go with finding a full IPV6 representation (8 xdigit tokens, separated by colon) or any expression built of xdigit/colon/period that contains 2 adjacent colons.

```
datatable (ipv6:string) 
[
    'IPv6 test 198.192.0.127 2345:5:2CA1:0000:0000:567:5673:256/127 in a random string'
   ,'IPv6 test 198.192.0.127 2345:5:2CA1::567:5673:256/127 in a random string'
   ,'IPv6 test 198.192.0.127 ::ffff:198.192.0.127 in a random string'
   ,'IPv6 test 198.192.0.127 ::1 in a random string'
   ,'IPv6 test 198.192.0.127 :: in a random string'
]
| project pv6addr = extract(@"([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){7}[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}|[[:xdigit:]:.]*::[[:xdigit:]:.]*", 0, ipv6)
```

| pv6addr |
| --- |
| 2345:5:2CA1:0000:0000:567:5673:256 |
| 2345:5:2CA1::567:5673:256 |
| ::ffff:198.192.0.127 |
| ::1 |
| :: |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2VOsQqDMBTcA/mHh4sKYk1sYg0UWjp16y4OqQmS0qrEIIL13xtx7B13w3G8d0o6z+dbQ2SGiYvRWdO1MWBUYQQe4f0xcXB6dEDKU0pKmmYpoQXQ/MgEE/R2JSLz2I3xYlMuKOOHrWY6kGBlp/oP7MdDjGqMvjDY/qUbB/6tVMrCGfTsrGxcdAmiqhKzMq1xoq4XkhxXES/F+pcGCWQJbMvjH+Djy3rKAAAA)

Comment: I have some comprehensive IP regular expressions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74503707/3745413). The IPv6 regular expression handles all valid IPv6 text representations (expanded, compressed, expanded-mixed, and compressed-mixed). I use the regular expressions in my [IPvX IP calculator](https://github.com/rmaupin/IPvX).