# MySQL - IPv6 and IPv4 field type

Tags: mysql

What is the best field type to use in a MySQL database for storing both IPv4 and IPv6 IP addresses?

I don't need to do any processing on them, just store them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076714/max-length-for-client-ip-address

Answer (score 1):

I use String for storing IP ( I put IP in a json and I store it with type String in my db)