# Storing an IP as an unsigned int?

Tags: php, sql, optimization, ip

I read that the best way to store IP addresses in a database is to make an Unsigned Int(10) field. How do I convert the IP addresses using PHP? I've tried using

```
$this->ip = long2ip($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I found the way to convert it back to an IP address using

```
$this->ip = sprintf("%u", ip2long($result['ip']));
```

How do I convert the IP Address initially? Should I be using PHP for this? Or would it be better to integrate into the MySQL query?

Comment: Well according to this question the best datatype is not an Integer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038950/what-is-be-the-most-appropriate-data-type-for-storing-an-ip-address-in-sql-server

Comment: Not sure about the best datatype across the board, but in the case of Postgres I'd definitely say the best datatype was `Inet` rather than hacking it into anything else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`long2ip`](http://php.net/long2ip) converts an integer into the IP format and [`ip2long`](http://php.net/ip2long) does the inverse.

So use `ip2long` to convert `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` into an integer for storing it in the database and use `long2ip` after reading the integer from the database:

```
$long = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$ip   = long2ip($long);
```

Comment: Your explanation is correct but your usage in the snipped is incorrect.

Answer (score 12):

Better put this logic in your SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `table`
    (`ip`)
VALUES
    INET_ATON('192.168.0.1')
```

And then covert address back when selecting data:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(`ip`)
    FROM `table`
```

Comment: +1, especially because that should also support IPv6 -- although that probably never becomes reality :/

Comment: What is the advantage to using SQL over PHP?

Comment: Well, it's just better, to put database storage related logic in queries if that is possible. For example, if you upgrade your MySQL server to a new version and there will be some changes in the way that data is stored, those changes will be reflected in database functions as well. If you trust this logic to other tool, you might get a problem. But first of all, it's logical delegation of tasks, so that your code is more understandable.

Comment: @Markus IPv6 is a reality today. Rare enough that we can't bank on it, but common enough that we can't bank on it not being used either.

Answer (score 2):

I used this

```
function ip2int($ip) {
    $a = explode(".",$ip);
    return $a[0] * 256 * 256 * 256 + $a[1] * 256 * 256 + $a[2] * 256 + $a[3];
}
```

Comment: this one is better than the built-in one, imo, because it doesn't hit the sign issue

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL you can use the `INET_ATON` (ip2long equivalent) and `INET_NTOA` (long2ip) functions rather than doing the processing with PHP:

Answer (score 1):

You’ll want to convert the dotted string version of your IP using `ip2long`, and back using `long2ip`. Looks like you have it backwards right now.

```
$integer_ip = ip2long($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]); // => 1113982819
$dotted_ip  = long2ip($integer_ip);             // => "66.102.7.99"
```