# IP address storing in MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, ip, field

what is the right field type for IP address in mysql? and what is the right way of storing it using PHP?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it, and which version of IP you care about.

Comment: Depends on how you are gonna use it, but generally, think varchar will be better

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038950/what-is-be-the-most-appropriate-data-type-for-storing-an-ip-address-in-sql-server?

Comment: I just want to store users IP after registration. If something happens and I need users IP; I'll look.

Comment: In that case, use VARCHAR(39) so you can store all version IP's

Comment: I care about both IPv4 and IPv6

Comment: @user552828, @Sander - Saving IP addresses in VARCHAR fields is extremely inefficient. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 62):

[This tutorial](http://daipratt.co.uk/mysql-store-ip-address/) might help you.

The most efficient way of saving IPv4 addresses is with an INT field (not VARCHAR as you might expect). You convert them using PHP's [`ip2long`](http://ca.php.net/ip2long) and back using either MySQL's [`INET_NTOA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) function or PHP's [`long2ip`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php) function.

If you need to store IPv6, you'll want to use a BINARY field instead and PHP's [`inet_pton`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) function.

Comment: there's no builtin function named `ip2bin`. you can easily write one yourself though: `function ip2bin($ip) { return inet_pton($ip); }`

Comment: @knittl - I added the function I was referring to. My bad for not including it.

Comment: @francois: why not simply use `inet_pton`? it already works with almost all string representations of ip addresses, no need for complicated transformations

Comment: @knittl - That's a good point, actually. Let me update my answer.

Comment: if you're running a 64-bit system the MySQL INT field must be UNSIGNED

Comment: Even, if you running a 32-bit system, it will be considered as BIGINT UNSIGNED for computations. For IPv6 addresses use INET6_ATON() and INET6_NTOA() with HEX() and UNHEX() functions to store IP addresses as BINARY column. Still data type depends on what you want to do with this data. Check here http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/08/how-to-store-ip-address-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 53):

you can store them in a binary field with a length of 128 bits (16 bytes, `BINARY(16)` or `VARBINARY(16)`).
to convert any ip address to its binary representation, you can use the php function [`inet_pton`](http://php.net/inet_pton). this method will work for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. [`inet_ntop`](http://php.net/inet_ntop) can be used to get back the string representation of the stored ip address (regardless of version)

Comment: Can I use it both for IPv6 and IPv4

Comment: @user552828: yes, you can use it for both ipv4 and ipv6

Comment: but they say that IPv6 can be 45 characters long in case of tunneled ip, so is 128bit lenght is ok? Im asking because Im not soo good at coding , Im a newbie

Comment: an ipv6 address will always be of length 128 bits. different string representations can give different string lengths. with tunneled ipv6 addresses it could look like the following: `1234:4567:89ab:cdef:1234:ffff:127.127.127.127` (not entirely correct, usually it's `::ffff:127.127.127.127` (80 bits zero, 16 bits one, 32 bits ipv4 address))

Comment: `pton` = *presentation* to *network*. `ntop` = *network* to *presentation*.

Comment: @knittl It appears that `BINARY(16)` is not fine to use in this case. check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55347251/1640660 so `VARBINARY(16)` should be used instead.

Answer (score 17):

Generally you can go with VARCHAR(45) as it will be long enough to even store IPv6.

Comment: IPv6 can be 45 characters if you have a tunneled address. Granted it's an edge case, but why not future proof.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that :)

Comment: so, you basically use up to 45 bytes for addresses which use 16 byte max? seems quite wasteful to me … (with ipv4 addresses it gets worse: 4 byte address and 15 byte string repr.)

Comment: @Knittl you dont use empty data with VARCHAR, that's only with CHAR, see this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Comment: yes, that's why i wrote "15 byte for ipv4 addresses" and not 45 byte. it still uses ~4 times as much space as necessary