# Yii framework: How do I use CActiveRecord.beforeFind()?

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii-events

I'm in a need to use `beforeFind(`) in a child class of `CActiveRecord`.

Basically, I need to convert some data from before actual search in the DB is performed.

How do I alter the about-to-occur-find-operation that is about to take place, inside `beforeFind()`? Messing with `$this` attributes is not useful since its not even populated, which is a little surprise. 
I've seen that the documentation mentions a "hidden CDbCriteria parameter" but I just couldn't guess how to use it... . Unfortunately, the documentation on this subject is slim.

What I need to do is rather simple: I've got a table column for storing IP addresses. The most efficient design from scalability perspective, is to use a VARBINARY(16) data type for the column. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427786/ip-address-storing-in-mysql-database) SO question page (and answers) on this.
So, the cleanest solution would be to have `beforeFind()`, `afterFind()` and `beforeSave()` work transparently for the users.

In the code stack, the IP addresses would be the normal dotted-quad and in the DB level, its whatever that goes into the field after utilizing PHP's `inet_pton()` method in those after/before hook methods.

It was supposed to be cool. and it is cool - with `afterFind()` and `beforeSave()`, where I have the ip_address attribute of the object at hand, at the mercy of my uber-manipulation powers.

Here's the point, and the need: thing is, I don't know how to achieve that on `beforeFind()`. I cannot do a blind `mergeWith()` as I need to check if ip_address attribute is part of the original criteria, and that I don't know how to do.

Help!
TIA :)

Answer (score 1):

I've got [this nice suggestion](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/33422-how-to-use-cactiverecordbeforefind/page__view__findpost__p__160925) on yii forums. 
Basically, I just need to override findByAttributes() in the child class and I'm done :)