# MySQL store IP as int for higher performance?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with a lot of queries per second. The query search for the IP address value.
So is it reasonable to store IPs like for example `34.549.53.23` as int value: 345495323?
Will the queries be faster?

I know for example that `192.168.1.1` and `192.16.81.1` are both stored as 19216811 but this does not matter.

Comment: 34.549.53.23 and 123.1.2.3.1.2.3 arn't valid IPs

Comment: @Dinistro its an example !!

Comment: what's the point of storing 3212321321 if you cant use it as an IP?

Comment: @SatishSharma: You can correct them with valid values, though not real. BTW: `123.1.2.3.1.2.3` too is not correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427786/ip-address-storing-in-mysql-database

Comment: We'd have to see the queries to know if they'd be improved with this optimization, but in general, an index on integer is more performant than an index on an equivalent string because the integer entries are smaller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I think this is micro optimization you can use the function `ip2long()` to convert an ascii representation of an IP address to a 32bit integer and `long2ip()` to convert it back.

Try it:

```
$int = ip2long('192.168.0.1');
echo $int; // 3232235521

$ip = long2ip(3232235521);
echo $ip; // 192.168.0.1
```

Btw, the conversion between a string representation of an IP and it's integer representation works not like you expect. You see that 192.168.0.1 is converts *not* to 19216801. Look at it, it is obvious that this couldn't be reconverted. Is it 19.216.80.1 or 192.168.0.1?

An IP address is a 32bit integer which is stored in binary format (like any number). Lets have a look at the binary representation of `3232235521` `(192.168.0.1)`:

```
11000000 10101000 00000000 00000001
```

I've split into 8bit units (bytes) for better readability. This is what the computer sees. But this is hard to remember for humans.

The ascii representation from that will be build by convert the value of every byte to decimal and separate them by a `.`:

```
11000000 => 192
10101000 => 168
00000000 =>   0
00000001 =>   1
```

.. what gives you `192.168.0.1`, what is more easy to remember by humans. (Beside some other advantages regarding the readability of subnet groups)

Comment: looks good. i wonder what op thinks

Comment: Short, simple, bang on target!

Answer (score 5):

Yes the queries will be faster. Also to save the IP as integer use the mysql's `INET_ATON()` and to get back the IP address from integer use `INET_NTOA()` . Pleas refer this page for more info

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html

If you are trying with PHP you could use `ip2long()` and `long2ip()` viceversa

Refer http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php