# Design store ip table sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ip

I am creating database for a website and want to store IP Address of user when they are login,
what data type should I be using for IP? does it need to support IPv6?

Is this script good and does it need to pars IP?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [userId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ip] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [dateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_temp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: you might be interested in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server

Comment: See [Maximum length of the textual representation of an IPv6 address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166132/maximum-length-of-the-textual-representation-of-an-ipv6-address)

Comment: bummi peterm thanks for your links, is it importent to have IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038950/what-is-the-most-appropriate-data-type-for-storing-an-ip-address-in-sql-server) which describes how to store IP addresses in database.

Comment: thanks for your link, but actually its not my answer all of my question.