# IP, MAC & Vlan IDs format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, validation

I am working on an ASP.NEt mvc web application, that stores data regarding network devices.but I need to know if there is a global format for these numbers:-

1. IP address
2. MAC address
3. VLanID
4. subnetmask

And is there any data annotations I can use to implement data validation for these numbers?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For IP Address:

```
IPAddress ip = new IPAddress((long)ips);
return ip.ToString();
```

To store  IP address, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038950/what-is-the-most-appropriate-data-type-for-storing-an-ip-address-in-sql-server)

For MacAddress, i dont know any existing formats. but you can take it from string.

```
string macAddStr = "00E0EE00EE00";
string macAddStrNew = macAddStr;
int insertedCount = 0;
for(int i = 2; i < macAddStr.Length; i=i+2)  
macAddStrNew = macAddStrNew.Insert(i+insertedCount++, ":");
```