# Best way to sort by IP addresses in SQL

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, spiceworks

I connect to my SpiceWorks database via PHP using the SQLITE3 PDO. I am trying to display a list of devices in order by IP address. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT name, ip_address FROM `devices` ORDER BY ip_address
```

The problem with this is that it organizes them weird like this:

[image]

Is there any easy way to fix this problem?

It is not possible for me to edit the database because it would through SpiceWorks off. I need a way to do this in SQL.

Comment: That depends on how you're storing your IP addresses. Is it a string column? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: Yes. SpiceWorks stores them in a varchar field. There is no way for me to change that because SpiceWorks uses the database too.

Comment: You have to substring that in segments separated by each dot and order as desired.Mysql has substring_index,I`m not familiar with sqlite.

Comment: Not sure about sqlite, but in mysql you could `ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address)` ... don't know if sqlite has a similar function

Comment: INET_ATON is not a valid SQLITE function.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried INET_ATON function? This is probably a late answer, but maybe it'll help others.

```
SELECT name, ip_address
FROM devices
ORDER BY
INET_ATON(ip_address)
```

Comment: `INET_ATON` is a MySQL function. The question is about SQLITE.

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented like this:

```
SELECT IP FROM iplist ORDER BY

CAST(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')-1) AS INTEGER),  

   CAST(substr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)) ,1, instr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)),'.')-1) AS INTEGER), 

        CAST(substr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)) ,1, instr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)),'.')))+length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)) ,1, instr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)) ,1, instr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)),'.')))+length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)),'.')-1) AS INTEGER), 

        CAST(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)) ,1, instr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)),'.')))+length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)) ,1, instr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)) ,1, instr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)),'.')))+length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)),'.')))+ length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+length(substr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)) ,1, instr(substr(trim(IP),length(substr(trim(IP),1,instr(trim(IP),'.')))+1,length(IP)),'.')))+1,length(trim(IP))) AS INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY
CAST(substr(ip_address,1,instr(ip_address,'.')) AS NUMERIC),
CAST(substr(ip_address,instr(ip_address,'.'), instr(substr(ip_address,instr(ip_address,'.')))) AS NUMERIC),
```

Something like that should work. It'll be nasty though. (This **should** sort by the first two octets...)

Comment: basically, sort by the string from first letter to the first dot, then from the first dot to the next dot after the first dot...

Comment: That still won't work, it will still sort `113` before `20`. You need to convert each substring to a number for sorting purposes.

Comment: ^ Fixed. Added CASTs -- NB I'm not able to test this at the moment; there may be some nice off-by-ones in this.

Comment: Guys read my answer below. It will work. 100% true. In my project it's implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You have the fields as VARCHAR or some other character field, so it is sorting them by the first number. You need to CAST the type to a number in the order by statement.

Like this:

```
SELECT name, ip_address
FROM devices
ORDER BY

CAST(PARSENAME([ip_address], 4) AS INT),
CAST(PARSENAME([ip_address], 3) AS INT),
CAST(PARSENAME([ip_address], 2) AS INT),
CAST(PARSENAME([ip_address], 1) AS INT)
```

Just not sure if this works in SQLlite.....

Comment: no such function: PARSENAME... PARSENAME is not a valid SQLITE function.

Comment: I found this: http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/97998-reports-sort-by-ip-address

Comment: This is a valid solution for SQL Server.  See: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/sort-ip-address.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since I only cared about the last octet, I was able to use the very simple

```
SELECT name, ip_address FROM `devices`
ORDER BY CAST(substr(ip_address, 10) AS NUMERIC) DESC;
```

My ip had 9 characters before the last octet