# sql server 4 byte unsigned int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Does anyone know of any work around by which i can save unsigned integers (0 to 4294967295) simply using 4 bytes instead of using 8 bytes and bigint?

I know we can create user defined datatypes and create a constraint on them to not allow negative values but that still does not allow me to enter values over 2147483647.  I only want to use 4 bytes but be able to save integer values greater than 2147483647 but less than 4294967295.

> Possible duplicate:
>   [4 byte unsigned int in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306291/4-byte-unsigned-int-in-ms-sql)

Comment: datatypes vary a fair bit from implementation to implementation .. which sql server are you using mssql ? mysql ?

Comment: the "sql-server" tag is for Mircosoft SQL Server.

Comment: m using sql server 2008 :-) thats why i tagged it sql-server

Answer (score 3):

There is no unsigned type available to you, so you could create one using the UDT, or opt for the larger data type. If you do it in a UDT you are going to exceed the 4 bytes again.

The extreme hack would be to apply an offset automatically to your stored value after you read it, by adding -2^31 but this is a real hacky way to go about it and confusing for anyone viewing the code etc, not to mention the potential for mistakes / things being missed. I wouldn't recommend the hack at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Binary(4).  Wrap it in a UDT if you want.

Comment: This actually uses 6 bytes: the 4 data bytes + 2 bytes overhead for the binary data type.

Comment: The overhead is why I went with an `int` with a check constraint instead of `binary(2)` for a `uint16`. You also might need to consider endianness with a `binary(x)` storage format.

Comment: @JeffMeatballYang No, `varbinary` has a 2-byte overhead, `binary` has none.  See here: http://www.smattie.com/2013/01/14/sql-server-data-types/  (also, sorry, but somehow I missed your comment three years ago)

Comment: @BenMosher See my previous comment and link.  `binary(n)` has no additional storage overhead.

Comment: @RBarryYoung -- ah, that makes sense, since it's fixed-width. I still don't want to manage endianess, though, even for two bytes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This solution may be slightly confusing but will work for your purposes. Storing values bigger than 2^31-1 as integers causes overflow and appears as negative number. You can still store your values as integers and reinterpret them in code.

Comment: Is the behavior of the overflow defined? or does it vary by implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by RBarry, try using this:

```
declare @bi binary(4) = cast(2147483648 as bigint)

declare @i int = cast(@bi as binary(4))

select @i  

declare @bi2 bigint = cast(cast(@i as binary(4)) as bigint)

select @bi2
```