# Why doesn't SQL Server support unsigned datatype?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes, unsigned-integer

I am specifically thinking about unsigned `int`.

Here is a practical example: what do you do when your identity column maxes out? It's possible to either go `BigInt` (8 bytes storage instead of 4) or to refactor the application to support negative integers, and even to create your own rules as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306291/4-byte-unsigned-int-in-sql-server/306300#306300); neither of those options are optimal.

`UInt` would be an ideal solution, but SQL Server does not offer it (where MySQL does).

I understand that unsigned datatypes are not part of the SQL standard (SQL-2003) but still seems like a waste to me.

What is the reason of not including these (in SQL Server or in the standard)?

Comment: Ask the SQL Server design team..... also: are you **really** gonna max out even 2 **BILLION** INT IDENTITY values?? **REALLY?!?!?!** If you have more than 2 billion rows of whatever it is you're dealing with, I bet you can spare some disk space and use a BIGINT as IDENTITY....

Comment: What do you mean marc_s? That's only an insert every 800ms for 50 years straight, your tables don't have that kind of activity? :)

Comment: @Mike M: Not all of us work on mickey mouse apps... we've used 3 billion+ of a bigint in under 2 years. Peak is > 2000 rows per second.

Comment: @gbn I didn't mean to imply that no one had that load. However, as has been said, if you DO have > 2000 rows per second, an extra 2B isn't going to help your cause.

Comment: @marc_s, right…   Let's avoid any design related questions on SO. After all, the team behind the product has for sure the answer.  
I hear what you say about the number of values, but my question was not on choosing the right datatype; this was only given as an example.   
Thanks for taking the time to add a nice formatting to your comment though, it's appreciated.

Comment: @Mike M and @marc_s, if I was working on a system with 2 billion rows table, I may pay attention to wasted storage. I may pay attention to the index page size and to the index scan performance. In such conditions, I would like not wasting space.

Comment: @Nip: I'm all for having design related questions - but often, it's really not possible as an outsider to know what the reasoning or the thoughts behind a certain decision are. That's all....

Comment: Why should negative identity values be a problem for your application? In what way are negative identity values suboptimal?

Comment: Just to play devil's avocado for a second - using a uint instead of an int can be useful to specify *intent* about a property of an object. For example, you wouldn't want to place an order with a negative quantity, or record a transaction with a negative amount (a common bug). It's not always about being able to reach a higher maximum value.

Comment: @marc_s, there are a lot of other uses for an int than to just store a big number.  A bit mask field shouldn't be stored in a signed int, or like Neil Barnwell says, your intent is not shown by having a signed int in that case, and you probably shouldn't use the leftmost bit.  There are other cases, and it depends on the data you are storing.

Comment: "My database is bigger" :p

Comment: For the record, my company (very large bank) has a production Splunk logging database which accumulates more than 380 billion rows of data per year (rolling size, one year always online).

Comment: @Mike M and marc_s: 2 billions rows are not that uncommon. But anyway, 2 billions of identity values are not 2 billions of rows. It's possible that many low numbers belonged to deleted rows, or failed transactions.

Comment: Storing an IPv6 address as two BIGINTs would be nice, but the signed part of it will make checking ranges harder.

Comment: It's probably an inefficient use of space (9 bytes), but I like the idea mentioned below about using a zero-scaled decimal type. Even `decimal(16,0)` goes out to 1 quadrillion values.  Some quick math came out to 1 quadrillion rows with decimal(16,0) would use 7.99 petabytes for just that one column unless it reduces the storage cost based on the actual value saved like in `(n)varchar`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If I had to guess, I would say that they are trying to avoid a proliferation of types.  Generally speaking there isn't anything that an unsigned integer can do that a signed integer can't do. As for the case when you need a number between 2147483648 and 4294967296 you probably should go to an 8 byte integer since the number will also eventually exceed 4294967296.

Comment: I guess this is the closest we can get to an answer for this question. Thanks.

Comment: If 'proliferation of types' could have saved some space/money, why do you guess this could have been the evil.

Comment: Fetching rows by their value will also be slower (i.e. `ORDER BY ABS(Id)`), especially if the column is a clustered primary key. For example, using a 32-bit unix timestamp is often a handy way to shave 4 bytes off a standard SQL datetime.

Comment: Today I'm facing with the task of converting the endianess of 32-bit unsigned numbers stored as strings directly in SQL Server. It would be trivial to achieve using BINARY(4) and reverse if SQL Server accepted unsigned integers...

Answer (score 84):

For that purpose you could use -2,147,483,648 as the seed value.

```
Identity(-2147483648, 1)
```

Comment: Ha I absolutely love this answer. I'm not sure I'd ever implement it but it definitely solved the issue of having half your ids not used.

Comment: good solution...not great....but answers the problem...using the min_value as zero (0)...effectively using the Kelvin scale ;)

Comment: This is such a horrible idea

Answer (score 60):

I found a similar question [on Microsoft Office Dev Center.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/b91f934a-01a1-4146-9501-0dc228156e04/data-type-for-unsigned-integer?forum=transactsql)

The reply from Jim Hogg (Program Manager) has some pro's and con's for adding unsigned int's.  The major con is the rules to implement implicit type conversions become a nightmare to get right.

The request was closed as "Won't Fix".

Comment: The link is not working anymore, so I can't read the original answer. But I believe that the problem is not that it's a nightmare; it's that there is not a standard which says how to do it. They could do what MySQL does for example (I don't think other DBMSs support UNSIGNED), but if another DBMS adds support for signs, they could use different rules. Conversion design is an important matter. JavaScript is an example of what happens when it's not taken seriously.

Comment: Updated link - Jim Hogg's comment on MSSN Office Developers Forum.

Comment: I have a strong need for unsigned integer types because they represent the _nature_ of the data being stored more accurately. I fully understand the concerns about implicit conversion, but that shouldn't be a problem because implicit conversion _to_ any  unsigned type from a signed type shouldn't be allowed - which neatly solves _that_ problem (I'm assuming that ISO SQL requires it?). Ultimately my frustration is that as applications devs we're told to model our data as close to the business-domain as possible, but then we're hamstrung by our tools that stop us from doing that.

Answer (score 2):

They don't support the SIGNED and UNSIGNED keyword because they're not standard. In SQL standard, all numeric types are signed.

UNSIGNED (and SIGNED, which is the default) are MySQL extensions that can be useful to store higher unsigned numbers in the same amount of bytes, and disallow negative numbers.

Comment: "In SQL standard all numeric types are signed" - yes, but ISO SQL is **painfully** at-odds with the day-to-day challenges of data-modelling and application development. It becomes an absolute necessity to violate the ISO SQL spec in order to ship something usable.

Comment: UNSIGNED types are desirable, but not that important. Most DBMSs don't support them, which keeps type conversions (and therefore operations between different types) much simpler. If you want to avoid negative numbers, add a CHECK constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `DECIMAL`. Huge decimal - `DECIMAL(38, 0)`. Should suffice for a month or two...

```
CREATE TABLE IdentityTest
(
    Id DECIMAL(38, 0) IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO IdentityTest VALUES('John'),('Peter'),('Tom')

SELECT * FROM IdentityTest

DROP TABLE IdentityTest
```

Which produces this result:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Peter |
| 3 | Tom |

Comment: Per the documentation, you'll have issues with this if using Informatica:

`Informatica only supports 16 significant digits, regardless of the precision and scale specified.`

Answer (score 0):

Take 32 bit(8 byte) int for example.
The range of 32 bit int is from -2^31 to 2^31-1.
It takes 31 bit to record the value you assigned and only 1 bit to record the sign of value.

So the answer to your question is "Unnecessary". Even though every value you assigned is positive, it waste only 1 bit per value. Creating a new datatype for saving only 1 bit per value is not a good way to optimize storage space.

Comment: Sometimes there are other reasons than just storage space. If I want to use unsigned values in a program (and many languages support such a thing for good reason), I shouldn't have to perform a conversion to retrieve/store those values in a database. Someone then looking at the raw data has to adjust the values manually or mentally to really visualize the state in the program. Usability and utility are very important factors that seem to have gone completely ignored by the SQL Server team in this case.

Comment: If you need to jump to BIGINT from INT just because INT does not support unsigned, the waste is 4 bytes per row, not 1 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Set your DB to have the min identity
Identity(-2147483648, 1)

Then when loading into your .net UInt64 variable add 2147483648 to it.  then
-2147483648  becomes 0
-1000000000  becomes 1147483648

- But also in most cases the internal keys shouldn't be exposed to clients,  I typically use a separate key which can be anything like 'ABCKey1"

However I'm in agreement that the datatype is large enough in 99% of the systems out there.    If you really need more you could use a GUID - however that sucks for Index's unless you use the next sequential GUID.

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where unsigned numbers are required in SQL server. For example, it may be necessary to store the equivalent of a binary value as an integer. In this case, for the 32-bit binary value, it is necessary to use 64-bit bigint instead of the 32-bit int data type.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a signed int to an unsigned number in T-SQL:

```
SELECT (CAST(x AS bigint) & 0xffffffff)
```

To convert an unsigned number to a signed int in T-SQL:

```
Select CAST(-((~CAST(x as bigint) + 1) & 0xffffffff) as int)
```

These conversions can be very useful. The number must be representable as a UINT32.