# Sql server datatypes , for storing a Positive number

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i want to add a column inside my SQL Server 2008 R2, which stored a Switch Ports numbers , which always have positive numbers such as 1 ,2, 3 ,4 , 5,6 ,etc...
I can use Integer, but is there a more appropriate data type for storing positive integers ?
Thanks

Comment: Nope. `int` and a `CHECK` constraint if you want to be sure is about the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tinyint**

> A SQL Server system datatype, it is a tiny integer column that holds
>   whole numbers between 0 and 255, inclusive. Storage size is 1 byte.

The TinyInt allow you to insert Positive numbrs only but you can have values between 0 and 255...

See [Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d2da1)

**[SQL SERVER NUMERIC DATATYPE](http://www.w3computing.com/sqlserver/numeric-data-types/)**

Answer (score 5):

No, there is not. SQL server doesn't support unsigned integers.

Some more details on this can be found on [Why doesn't SQL Server support unsigned datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451967/why-doesnt-sql-server-support-unsigned-datatype)