# Best Sql server 2008 R2 data type to store NumberOfEmployees . value that can be >=zero

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on building a database for my HR system. where i need to store the number of employee at each department . this number can be any thing from zero to 999999 ... now i am storing the EmployeeCount as int , and i am checking that the user should not enter negative numbers ,, so i will not end up having values such as -30 , -100 , etc..

now i am not sure if there is a better datatype to be used inside the sql server 2008 r2 ,to represents EmployeeCount, which  only allow storing positive int ? i nearest datatype is tinyint but it only allow having up to 255..

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't SQL Server support unsigned datatype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451967/why-doesnt-sql-server-support-unsigned-datatype)

Comment: Just use an int and add a constraint that it must be >= 0.

Comment: ... and here is the how-to: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28642.t-sql-check-constraints.aspx

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter. I should have included a link. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` is probably the best datatype for you in this case.

There is not a standard way of saying "positive int", but just plain "int" is the closest thing to it, and then let your application (or db constraints, or sprocs, or triggers, etc.) make sure that the value entered ends up >= 0.

Comment: so int is the way to go ...  not sure why there is not a datatype similar to tinyint but that can store  number  > 255???

Comment: `tinyint` is the way it is because it's designed to require 1-byte, meaning that the biggest range of values possible is 0-255.  Any vendor could also have created `negativetinyint` if they wanted, and define it as, say, -1 to -256, but specialization of datatypes becomes more trouble than they are worth at some point...

Answer (score 1):

You can only use SMALLINT if the maximum of employeecount is 32768. Other than that, you would need an INT and you could add a constraint for values to be positive, when designing your table. Something like:

```
EmployeeCount int NOT NULL CHECK  (EmployeeCount > 0)
```

If you really want to, you can also define your own type. Read this for further information:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933121(v=sql.80).aspx